# Ipad animating images crashing issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, animation

I have an application in which I have taken imageview as a background and in that imageview I am using 89 images to make an animation.Here's my code to do the animation

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

NSString *cachesDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    
NSLog(@"cachesDirectoryPath: %@", cachesDirectoryPath);
    CPIAppDelegate *obj=(CPIAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    arrayOfImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    viewMenu.hidden = obj.buttonStatus;
    for (int i=0; i<IMAGE_ANIMATION_COUNT; i++) {
//  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/streamvideo351_frame%d.jpg",cachesDirectoryPath,i]];
        [arrayOfImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"streamvideo351_frame%d.jpg",i]]];

    }

    BackGrdImage.animationImages=arrayOfImages;
    BackGrdImage.animationDuration =5.0; 
    BackGrdImage.animationRepeatCount =3;
    [BackGrdImage startAnimating];
    [arrayOfImages removeAllObjects];

}
```

and in dealloc method I am using

```
[imageAnimations release];
[BackGrdImage removeFromSuperview];
[BackGrdImage release];
```

it works fine on simulator But crashes on Ipad.What actually happens in ipad is sometimes it gets blink and some time time it disappear.So please help me out with this friends.I am also releasing the array on `-(void)viewWillDisappear` So please friends help me out with it Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably not the issue but make sure you call [super viewWillAppear:animated] at some point in your viewWillAppear: method.

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashing because BackGrdImage animating only one time after that you releasing the array

> [arrayOfImages removeAllObjects];

and

> BackGrdImage.animationRepeatCount =3;

due to this your image goes animating second time but BackGrdImage does not get arrayOfImages for animation therefore your app going to crash.

There is one way when your image animation three time means in 1.5 sec then after you have to call one method for releasing your arrayOfImages.
The above process sure will work out.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are getting memory warning. Because I don't think that device will support images array of 89 images/imageviews. Try debuggig your app on device.